# org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Early EOF thrown while uploading large file

Tags: java, jetty, apache-httpclient-4.x, netflix-zuul

While I am uploading large file(about 50 MB), I am getting  ***org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Early EOF*** excception. My jetty server version is "***9.2.9.v20150224***".Below is stack trace

```
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Early EOF
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput$3.noContent(HttpInput.java:505) ~[jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.read(HttpInput.java:124) ~[jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
at org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity.writeTo(InputStreamEntity.java:142) ~[httpcore-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:96) ~[httpcore-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:112) ~[httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:117) ~[httpcore-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:265) ~[httpcore-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.sendRequestEntity(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:231) ~[httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:237) ~[httpcore-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:122) ~[httpcore-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685) ~[httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487) ~[httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882) ~[httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:117) ~[httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) ~[httpclient-4.5.jar:4.5]
at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$2.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:192)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:408)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:302)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:129)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:676)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:246)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:208)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:471)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:763)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:801)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:142)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.flush(HttpOutput.java:237)
at java_io_Flushable$flush.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at SendResponseFilter.writeResponse(SendResponse.groovy:128)
at SendResponseFilter$writeResponse.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
at SendResponseFilter.writeResponse(SendResponse.groovy:102)
at SendResponseFilter.run(SendResponse.groovy:59)
at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112)
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197)
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161)
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.postRoute(FilterProcessor.java:92)
at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.postRoute(ZuulRunner.java:87)
at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.postRoute(ZuulServlet.java:107)
at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:88)
at realdoc.spider.SpiderServlet.service(SpiderServlet.java:66)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
at com.netflix.zuul.context.ContextLifecycleFilter.doFilter(ContextLifecycleFilter.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:259)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:222)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:504)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:172)
... 55 more
```

If anybody have any idea on this issue, please help me out.

Comment: in the logs in my environment it happens during two quick repeats of the same request. and there not only wirelessly as  frankie liuzzi suggested.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

These stacktraces just show the results of a connection termination, but not the reason why it terminated.

The `java.io.IOException: Broken pipe` means the connection was terminated, unexpectedly at the OS level.

The `org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException` during `org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush()` means the response body content was unable to finish flushing to the network as the connection was terminated.

The `org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Early EOF` during `org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.read()` means that while actively reading the Request (unclear if its body content or headers from stacktrace) from the Connection (a `java.nio.channels.SocketChannel` in this case), it terminated prematurely, and the complete HTTP Request was not received (headers and body content).

There might be other errors in the logs from either your client or the server that could indicate what is going on.
You could test that request with other tooling (like curl) to see if its your client, or the network, or Jetty.
You could also use a tool like wireshark to capture the network traffic and see where the connection termination originated (client or server)

Comment: Looks like question is still un-answered. What say ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

What I have found in the issue is that,in http header "Content-Length" was coming as something like xxx, because of sloppy internet wifi, before entire content was read(less than xxx), stream was closed and above exception is thrown.

Another issue is timeout issue.Before entire stream is read (as its a large file), due to timeout, stream is prematurely closed and exception thrown as above.

There can be other reasons also however I have faced those issues.

Comment: Hi RIPAN, I know you posted this so long ago, but we are suffering from the same issue when a user has spotty wifi...did you find a solution?

Comment: hi  Frankie, I did not find the solution however tried with a workaround, I set retry mechanism for the above issue.

Comment: The Idle Timeout would not close the connection if it's actively being used, no matter how long it was being used, or how large of content you are sending.